# SQL joining two tables, null same result

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

i'm trying to create a report for fields which have been updated, so basically like this:

```
| X | Y | Z | - Table 1 
| X | Y | P | - Table 2

| NUL | NUL | P | - Is what i want the outcome to be
```

Does anyone know if this is possible / how to approach it? I'm not very competent with SQL!
Cheers,

Comment: I think you need a right join.

Comment: Or a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then compare each field from the two tables possibly with a `CASE..WHEN..ELSE` statement.

Comment: how cum null null in first two columns?

Comment: How do you know which fields match?

Comment: it doesn't have to be null, it could be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple, but type intensive solution:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN (
     T1.Field1 = T2.Field1 OR (T1.Field1 IS NULL AND T2.Field1 IS NULL)
   ) THEN NULL ELSE T2.Field1 END AS Field1,
   CASE WHEN (
     T1.Field2 = T2.Field2 OR (T1.Field2 IS NULL AND T2.Field2 IS NULL)
   ) THEN NULL ELSE T2.Field1 END AS Field2
/** and so on **/
FROM
  Table1 T1
  FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.JoinField = T2.JoinField
```

You have to compare each field individually from the two tables. You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get all record from each tables

Also you have to check if the value in each table is NULL (`T1.Field1 IS NULL AND T2.Field2 IS NULL`). Remember NULL is never equals to any value neither NULL.

Note: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is maybe too broad, so you can use either `LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`, but you have to chose the join visely to match the business requirements.

Comment: This worked perfectly, cheers. I don't think the join type actually matters in this instance as i'm comparing the same two tables?

Comment: It only matters, when there could be difference between the list of keys you are using in the `ON` condition. With `FULL`, you can detect inserts and deletes too, with `LEFT`, you can detect inserts, with `RIGHT` you can detect deletes, with `INNER`, you can only detect updates. (All of them could detect updates). Since, you are searching for modifications, the two tables could not be the same (at least on the level of the data -> there could be both insert, deletes and updates).

Answer (score 1):

use [**`Left Outer Join`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the result

```
SELECT Table1.col1,
       Table1.col2,
       Table2.col3
FROM   Table2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1
              ON Table2.col3 = Table1.col3
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5992/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what the fields match, then you have a problem.  If you have an `id` that does the match, then you can use a `full outer join`.  A typical query in this situation would look like:

```
select id,
       (case when told.id is null then 'NEW'
             when tnew.id is null then 'DELETED'
             else 'UPDATED'
        end) as what,
       (case when told.col1 = tnew.col1 or told.col1 is null and tnew.col1 is null then NULL
             else tnew.col1
        end) as new_col1,
       (case when told.col2 = tnew.col2 or told.col2 is null and tnew.col2 is null then NULL
             else tnew.col2
        end) as new_col2,
       (case when told.col3 = tnew.col3 or told.col3 is null and tnew.col3 is null then NULL
             else tnew.col3
        end) as new_col3
from tableold told full outer join
     tablenew tnew
     on told.id = tnew.id;
```

This is likely to be what you want, unless your two tables only have one row each.

Answer (score 0):

HEre is my solution

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1( A varchar(10), B varchar(10), C varchar(10) , ID Int )

CREATE TABLE #Temp2( A varchar(10), B varchar(10), C varchar(10) , ID Int )

INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES('X','Y','Z',1)

INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES('X','Y','P',1)

SELECT 
    CASE #Temp1.A WHEN #Temp2.A THEN NULL ELSE #TEmp2.A END as A,
    CASE #Temp1.B WHEN #Temp2.B THEN NULL ELSE #TEmp2.B END as B,
    CASE #Temp1.C WHEN #Temp2.C THEN NULL ELSE #TEmp2.C END as C
 FROM #Temp1 full outer join #Temp2 on #Temp1.ID = #Temp2.ID
```

Use a case for each column, if column A from  #temp1 matches column b from #Temp2 then it will print null, else it will print #Temp2 column